# How to include more than one item in my json object in scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to include more than one item in my json object (currently I can only add one item),

In my scala class I have:

```
case class Api(row:Int,name:String,age:Int)
```

`Ok(Json.obj("status" -> "ok", "cars" -> carsBooked.map(_.row), "saved" -> saved, "failed" -> failed, "notBooked" -> Response.errors))` <<---- this works perfectly and I'm able to get a list of all the row in json, but how do i add name and age?

Ideally I wanna do something like `carsBooked.map(_.row._name etc..)`

Thanks!

Comment: Why not writing `Api` to `Json` conversion and using it in `.map`? Or Even deriving a conversion for whole `List`?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok that sound great! can you please share your code snippet? thanks!

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok you mean like implicit val residentFormat = Json.format[Api] ?

Comment: Basically, yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 1):

If we have

```
case class Api(row: Int, name: String, age: Int)
```

then we can [generate codecs automatically](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJsonAutomated).

```
object Api {
  implicit val apiReads: Reads[Api] = Json.reads[Api]
  implicit val apiWrites: OWrites[Api] = Writes.writes[Api]
}
```

and then we could write:

```
Ok(Json.obj("status" -> "ok", "cars" -> Json.toJson(carsBooked), "saved" -> saved, "failed" -> failed, "notBooked" -> Response.errors))
```

or we can actually make this also automated:

```
case class ApiResult(
  status: String,
  cars: List[Api],
  saved: List[String],
  failed: List[String],
  notSaved: List[String]
)
object ApiResult {
  implicit val apiResultReads: Reads[ApiResult] = Json.reads[ApiResult]
  implicit val apiResultWrites: OWrites[ApiResult] = Writes.writes[ApiResult]
}
```

```
val apiResult: ApiResult = ...
Ok(Json.toJson(apiResult))
```